# What's wrong with the coffee machine? What does the light bulb indicate?

Tags: coffee-machines, troubleshooting

What's wrong with the coffee machine?
What does the light bulb indicate?

[image]

Comment: It would probably help if you could add what the machine's type is (maybe it says on the back or bottom of the machine). That way someone might find the user manual which should explain what the indicator is for.

Answer (score 0):

Two lights are on in your photo and it's not clear which one you're talking about. I'll address both.

The silver buttons above the lights are used to select brewing mode. The light shown in the picture is for "hot water or steam". This is as opposed to "single brew / single shot" and "double brew / double shot".

The other light, red, round, and chrome bordered, indicates that descaling is in progress if solid and that the machine has detected limescale buildup and needs descaling if flashing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you
Your answer helped me a lot.